# Javascript: Radio button not checked value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have variable that get's value of checked radio button named: parentcheck
I wanna check if parentcheck is checked and =0 or if not checked. Tried if(parentcheck=='') for "not checked". it doesn't work.

```
var parentcheck = $(".parentcheck:checked").val();

            if(parentcheck=='0'){
                    $("#parent").hide();
                }
            if(parentcheck==''){
                    $("#parent").hide();
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, that selector you use will only return you elements with the class `.parentcheck` which are actually checked. By definition, that means every element it returns (as it always returns a set in jQuery) will be checked, so if the element you're looking for isn't checked then it won't be in the set. Something like this might be what you're after:

```
if (! $(".parentcheck").is(":checked")) {
    $("#parent").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!$('.parentcheck:').is(':checked')) {
    $('#parent').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually can't get your question, it should help you.

```
var $check = $('.parentCheck');
if ($check.val() == '' || toString($check.val()) == "0") {
    // do your stuff
}

if ($check.attr('checked')) {
    // checked, do your stuff
}
else { 
    // is not checked, do another stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.attr('checked')=='checked'`